# Limit of matrix inverse: $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} (A + \lambda I)^{-1} = \mathbf{0}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits

Let matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be positive semidefinite.

- Is it then true to that
  $$
  (A + \lambda I)^{-1} \to \mathbf{0} \quad (\lambda \to \infty) \quad ?
  $$
- If so, is the fact that $A$ is positive definite irrelevant here?

---

**My thoughts so far:**
$$
(A + \lambda I)^{-1} = \Big(\lambda( \frac{1}{\lambda}A + I ) \Big)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\lambda} \Big(\frac{1}{\lambda}A + I \Big)^{-1}
$$
I think that $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \Big( \frac{1}{\lambda}A + I \Big)^{-1} = I^{-1} = I$, but I don't know if I can just pass the $\lim$ through the inverse $(\cdot)^{-1}$ like that. If this is the case, then
$$
\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} (A + \lambda I)^{-1} = \lim_{\lambda \to \infty} (1/\lambda) \lim_{\lambda \to \infty} (A/\lambda + I)^{-1} = 0 \cdot I = \mathbf{0}
$$
as I'd like to show.

---

**Where this comes from:**

I'm trying to justify a claim made in an econometrics lecture. Namely,

$$
\textrm{Var}(\hat{\beta}^{\textrm{ridge}}) = \sigma^2 (X^{T}X + \lambda I)^{-1} X^T X [(X^T X + \lambda I)^{-1}]^T \to \mathbf{0}
$$
where $\hat{\beta}^\textrm{ridge}$ is the ridge estimator in a linear model, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ is the design matrix, and the equality is known. The limit, however, wasn't justified.

Comment: $A$ can be any matrix above. The point is, the inverse of a matrix is a continuous function in a neighbourhood of the identity, therefore since $A - \lambda I$ is going to eventually be invertible, we may pass the limit inside the inverse by continuity, giving the desired result by the continuity of scalar multiplication.

Comment: If $\|\cdot\|$ is a matrix norm, then the Neumann series guarantees that $A+\lambda I$ is invertible with $$(A+\lambda I)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\lambda^{n+1}}A^n, $$ which converges uniformly on the region $|\lambda| \geq \|A\|+\delta$ for any given $\delta > 0$. By the Weierstrass M-test, the limit as $\lambda\to\infty$ can be evaluated term-wise, proving the desired claim.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Great! That completes my line of reasoning. 
For others looking on, here's why there is a neighborhood of $I$ in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ in which $(\cdot)^{-1}$ is continuous:

$(\cdot)^{-1} : GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \to GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is continuous and $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is open in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ (see: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/810675/369800). 
[To understand the proof just linked: determinant continuous (see: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/121834/369800)
and adjoint continuous (see: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2031642/369800)]

Comment: Recall that the inverse matrix is the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) divided by the discriminant. Thus a "singularity" of the inversion only happens when the discriminant vanishes.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Can we use your reasoning to exchange limit and inverse order in $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty} (A+ \lambda B^TB)^{-1}$? $A$ is positive definite and B is a  full row rank $m\times n$ matrix.

Comment: @Mah I would like to think we can do so, but the argument is likely to be more convoluted. I think because $B^TB$ is positive definite, we can lower bound the smallest eigenvalue of $A+\lambda B^TB$ so that it goes to infinity with $\lambda$, then we can be done.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you for your answer.  $B^TB$ is positive semi-definite because $m<n$ and thus $B^TB$ is not invertible. But I agree with you we can lower bound the smallest eigenvalue of  $A+\lambda B^TB$. I am more interested in moving the limit inside the inverse and then moving the whole thing to the other side of a linear equation: \\ I have $x=\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}(A+\lambda B^TB)^{-1} y$, I want: $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}(A+\lambda B^TB)x= y$. Do you think it is possibly correct?

Comment: @Mah Oh, then I think it may happen a lot more often. A sufficient, but I don't think necessary, condition is that $(A+\lambda B^TB)$ has uniformly bounded smallest eigenvalue away from zero. That allows invertibility for each matrix, but also in the limit, which means you can switch the limit to the LHS. I don't think this is sufficient, since there may be conditions where the eigenvalues could go to zero but those that pertain to $x$ and $y$ (in some basis expansion) behave well. I am not being precise about the second part, but the first part should work.

Answer (score 4):

The eigenvalues of $A+\lambda I$ are of the form $\lambda+\mu$, where $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ (necessarily real). Then, for $\lambda$ sufficiently large, the eigenvalues of $A+\lambda I$ are all $>1$.

Note that a matrix $S$ that diagonalizes $A$ also diagonalizes $A+\lambda I$, let $A=SDS^{-1}$, with $D$ diagonal.

Then $(A+\lambda I)^{-1}$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues in $(0,1)$ and therefore
$$
\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}(A+\lambda I)^{-1}=
S\Bigl(\,\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}(D+\lambda I)^{-1}\Bigr)S^{-1}=0
$$
It is not necessary that $A$ is semipositive definite. Any symmetric matrix will do.

Answer (score 3):

The answer I liked the best was left in the comments by астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг, since it shows that $A$ does not need any special structure. Here I'm pulling his answer down and including a bit more detail.

---

We have
$$
(A + \lambda I)^{-1} = \Big(\lambda( \frac{1}{\lambda}A + I ) \Big)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\lambda} \Big(\frac{1}{\lambda}A + I \Big)^{-1},
$$
and we claim that  $\Big(\frac{1}{\lambda}A + I \Big)^{-1} \to I^{-1} = I \quad (\lambda \to \infty)$. 
Therefore,
$$
(A + \lambda I)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\lambda} \Big(\frac{1}{\lambda}A + I \Big)^{-1} \to 0 \cdot I = \mathbf{0} \quad (\lambda \to \infty),
$$
which was the desired result.

We complete the proof by showing the claim. Since $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is [open](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/810675/369800) in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, we find some $\epsilon > 0 $ such that the open ball $B(I, \epsilon) \subseteq GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. Hence, for sufficiently large $\lambda$, we know that $(A/\lambda + I) \in B(I, \epsilon) \subseteq GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. Also knowing that $(\cdot)^{-1} : GL_n \to GL_n$ is [continuous](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/810675/369800), we have
$$
\lim_{\lambda \to \infty}\Big(\frac{1}{\lambda}A + I \Big)^{-1} = \Big(\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{1}{\lambda}A + I \Big)^{-1}= (I)^{-1} = I,
$$
which completes the proof.

---

To understand the linked proof of the continuity of $(\cdot)^{-1}$, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/121834/369800) for justification that the determinant operator is continuous and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2031642/369800) for justification that the adjoint operator is continuous.

Comment: I may not be астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг anymore, but Teresa is very pleased that her idea was useful, even if it was two years ago!