# Prove if $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} A_k = A$, then $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} A_k^{-1} = A^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, limits

Let $\{A_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real $n \times n$ matrices. Suppose $A_k$ is invertible for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} A_k = A$, and that $A$ is invertible. Is $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} A_k^{-1} = A^{-1}$?

This feels like it should be true but I'm having trouble coming up with a proof.

Also, I think defining $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} A_k = A$ as componentwise convergence makes the most sense for my problem but any other insights are welcome!

Comment: What is $A_k$ ? a number ? a matrix ? a function ? If it's a matrix (as the tags let me guess), how do you define $\lim_{k\to \infty }A_k=A$ ? componentwise ?

Comment: Good point, I suppose componentwise makes the most sense for my context

Comment: All norms on finite-dimensional vector spaces are equivalent, and component-wise convergence is equivalent to convergence in any of them.

Comment: @saulspatz: This doesn't answer the question : "how does the OP defines $\lim_{k\to \infty }A_k=A$ ?".

Comment: @Surb:  I think the edit to the original post, defining convergence componentwise, is adequate (though if you wanted to explore alternative meanings in an Answer, that is invited).

Comment: I think it likely that this has been asked and answered before.  It follows from the [continuity of matrix inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810670/continuity-of-the-inverse-matrix-function/810675) with a bit of bookkeeping for the sequence of matrices.

Answer (score 6):

Sine $A_k$ converge, so do their determinants (which are polynomial functions of the entries), and the limit of the determinant is NOT zero, so do their cofactors (which are polynomial functions of the entries) and so do the cofactors over the determinant, which are the entries of the inverses.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is asking whether $\Phi : GL(n, \mathbb{R}) \to GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ defined by
$$\Phi(A) = A^{-1}$$
is continuous. This is true. In fact, $\Phi$ is differentiable. Let $||\cdot||$ denote the operator norm on $M(n, \mathbb{R})$. A geometric series type argument yields that for $H \in M(n, \mathbb{R})$ with $||H|| < 1$,
\begin{align}
(I + H)^{-1} &= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}(-1)^kH^k \\
&= I - H + H^2 - \dots \\
&= I - H + O(||H||^2).
\end{align}
Now let $A \in GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ be arbitrary. For $H \in M(n, \mathbb{R})$ we have
$$(A + H) = A(I + A^{-1}H)$$
Hence if $||A^{-1}H|| < 1$, then $A + H$ is invertible. Since $||A^{-1}H|| \leq ||A^{-1}|| \cdot ||H||$, $A + H$ is invertible whenever $||H|| < \frac{1}{||A^{-1}||}$ and
\begin{align}
(A + H)^{-1} &= (A(I + A^{-1}H))^{-1} \\
&= (I + A^{-1}H)^{-1}A^{-1} \\
&= (I - A^{-1}H + O(||H||^2))A^{-1} \\
&= A^{-1} - A^{-1}HA^{-1} + O(||H||^2).
\end{align}
Hence $D\Phi(A)H = -A^{-1}HA^{-1}$.