# Limit of inverses

Tags: matrices, limits, inverse

Given an invertible matrix $M$ which depends on a real parameter $\alpha$. Is the limit $\lim_{\alpha - \alpha_0} \left( M^{-1} \right) $ same as $ \left( \lim_{\alpha - \alpha_0} M\right)^{-1}$, i.e. does the following hold

\begin{equation}
 \lim_{\alpha - \alpha_0} \left( M^{-1} \right)  \overset{\mathrm{?}}{=} \ \left( \lim_{\alpha - \alpha_0} M\right)^{-1} 
\end{equation}
Or is there any relation between these quantities (say one is less or equal to the other)?

Comment: The equality holds, provided $\lim _{a\to a_0} M(a)$ is invertible. So excluding stuff like $aE,\ a\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The map $M\mapsto M^{-1}$ is continuous on $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810670/continuity-of-matrix-inversion). Hence the answer is affirmative.